# mySQL query not working; using HAVING

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that contains repeating events.  When my client adds a new event, I add a new record for each date.  So, everything contained in each record is identical except for the date.  Also, the timestamp indicates that the event is part of a group.

I need to select an event from a list so it can then be edited. However, since each event within a group is identical, I need to display only ONE of the records per group.

The SQL below ALMOST works.  The problem: mySQL seems to randomly pick the record from the group.  Sometimes, it chooses the first record from the group, sometimes the last, sometimes in the middle.  I need to control which record it chooses, since some events have already passed.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_events
WHERE repeats = 0
group by timestamp
having count(*) >= 2
ORDER BY date ASC
```

Comment: Why are you using `GROUP BY` without any aggregates?

Comment: i am a newbie.  will this solve my problems?

Comment: you can do a select * with group by and or having.

Comment: timestamp is reserved word in mysql

Comment: Should I change the name of timestamp in my table ?

Comment: @ChrisGiesler Yes you should change the name. Can you add the error message, so we can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

the below query is what you want. just replace id with the field you are actually using to determine its a duplicate event.

```
select e.* from tbl_events e inner join (select id, count(*) count from tbl_events group by id) c on c.id = e.id where c.count >= 2;
```